# After installing Alfresco , when starting alfresco server giving error like Error: Could not find or load main class {ALF_HOME}

Tags: tomcat, alfresco

After installing Alfresco , when starting alfresco server giving error like

```
Error: Could not find or load main class {ALF_HOME}
```

So what is the solution of this error ?

[image]

Comment: Could you give us the whole log (The might be an upper error).

Comment: This is a detailed log from start to end

Comment: There's quite a bit of log above that which'll tell us what has gone wrong!